# HttpContext.Current.User is null in ControllerBase(asp.net mvc)

Tags: asp.net-mvc, authentication, controller

I have a `ControllerBase` class in an ASP.NET MVC Application. The other controllers inherit from `ControllerBase`.

I want to access `HttpContext.User.Identity.Name`, but `HttpContext` is `null`. What's the matter?

```
public ControllerBase()
        {
            var dataManager=new DataManager();
            if (HttpContext.User.Identity.IsAuthenticated) // throws error
            {                    
                ViewData["assets"] = ud.BalanceFreeze + ud.Balance + ud.BalanceRealty;
                ViewData["onaccount"] = ud.Balance;
                ViewData["pending"] = ud.BalanceFreeze;
                ViewData["inrealty"] = ud.BalanceRealty;
            }
```

Answer (score 11, accepted):

Try adding your code to this event in your ControllerBase:

```
protected override void Initialize(RequestContext requestContext){

}
```

Comment: I discovered that I needed to call base.Initialize(requestContext) inside this override otherwise I would get a NullReferenceException later.

Answer (score 5):

Your controller gets constructed before the HttpContext has been set by ASP.NET. Like Nik says, you need to put this code into an overridden method in your class.

I would also point out that depending on HttpContext directly will make it impossible to perform unit testing on any of your controllers that extend this class. This is why many of the methods (like the Execute method) in the `ControllerBase` class take a `RequestContext` as an argument. You can say:

```
protected override void Execute(System.Web.Routing.RequestContext requestContext)
{
    var currentUser = requestContext.HttpContext.User;
    ...
}
```

... which makes it possible to create and execute your controllers with "fake" contexts for unit testing purposes.